# Reduce List but avoid Null variables

Tags: r

Given a list with a null element:

```
l<-list(x=1,b=2,c=NULL)
```

How can I Reduce the list using '+' addition but avoid adding the NULL value? I tried

```
Reduce(l,"+",null.rm=T)
```

but I don't think its got null.rm. Any efficient way of solving this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to re-implement `cumsum`? Take a look at `?is.null` and `?Filter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just exclude null elements with:

```
l <- l[!sapply(l, is.null)]
```

is that what you want?

cheers

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with `Filter`.

```
Reduce('+', Filter(Negate(is.null), l))
```

This is also equivalent to `tail(cumsum(Filter(Negate(is.null), l)), 1)` or just good old-fashioned `do.call(sum, l)`.

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing as `cumsum` (although it would if you set `accumulate=TRUE`), so the reference to it seems misleading.